# How should I update progressbar using Ajax and MVC

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, jsp, spring-mvc

Being new to JSP I'm trying to get my head around things. Currently I'm trying to create a page which displays the progress of tasks running on the server. I have an undefined nr of running tasks, and I want to show these tasks on my jsp page. I currently have a working solution but the "tasks" div is updated every 3 seconds which means the bar animation is restarted and sometimes the pane "flickers"

Is there a non hacky way to do this without having to overwrite all the tasks html?

main JSP:

```
<div id="tasks"></div>
....
<script>
(function worker() {
    $.ajax({
        url : '/tasks/update_tasks',
        success : function(data) {
            $('#tasks').html(data);
        },
        complete : function() {
            setTimeout(worker, 3000);
        }
    });
})();
```

update_tasks.jsp:

```
<body>
<c:forEach var="task" items="${tasklist}">
    <h3>${task.name}</h3>
    <div class="progress">
        <div
            class="progress-bar progress-bar-success progress-bar-striped active"
            role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="${task.currentProgress}"
            aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"
            style="width: ${task.currentProgress}%">${task.currentProgress}%</div>
    </div>
</c:forEach>
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/tasks/update_tasks",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView retrieveUpdate() {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("/tasks/update_tasks");
    logger.debug("update tasks");
    //tasklist is an ArrayList<TaskBean>
    modelAndView.getModel().put("tasklist", tasksService.getTaskList());
    return modelAndView;
}
```

TaskBean:

```
public class TaskBean {
    private String name;
    private String customerId;
    private int currentProgress;

    public TaskBean()
    {
        currentProgress = 0;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getCustomerId() {
        return customerId;
    }
    public void setCustomerId(String customerId) {
        this.customerId = customerId;
    }
    public int getCurrentProgress() {
        return currentProgress;
    }
    public void setCurrentProgress(int currentProgress) {
        this.currentProgress = currentProgress;
    }



}
```

Comment: Instead of retrieving the tasks list and replacing them on each call, I would just update their state.
You can add a method to your controller that returns the tasks list as a JSON object then iterate through your progress bars (using JQuery) and update the percentage accordingly.